# Getting 'access denied' when trying to access an airport RSS feed

Tags: c, curl, rss, libcurl

I'm trying to access an airport RSS feed using the curl library in C. Whenever I try to access it, though, I get access denied error. The following is the code I'm using. It's almost identical to the example code at https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        CURL *curl;
        CURLcode res;
        char *feed_addr = "http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KUCP.rss";
        //airport not in the state I live

        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if(curl) {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, feed_addr);

                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

                // Perform the request, res will get the return code
                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
                // Check for errors
                if(res != CURLE_OK) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",curl_easy_strerror(res));
                }

                // always cleanup
                curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I've tried this with other websites besides weather.gov (google, youtube, mit.edu) and they all work just fine. But when I tried this, even with other airport RSS feeds (which can be found at http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/seek.php?state=pa&Find=Find), I get the same access denied error. I also get the same error when I set `feed_addr` to any weather.gov page.

To make this stranger, when I tried to access the feed using Python3's `urllib.request` module, it worked just fine. I can also access it just fine with Google Chrome. So I can rule out the idea that it doesn't want me accessing the feed.

Is there something that I'm missing? Is there a way to get the feed via the curl library? Or is there a way using a different library?

Comment: Can you access it with a browser? If you can, try to fake the same headers browser is sending. Who knows, what it is looking at..

Comment: Pass a value for `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` ?  You may also need Accept headers too.  Add as much as you can to look more like a normal browser and it'll probably start working.

Comment: @drew010 Thanks. That got me asking the right questions that eventually solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question (I did not originally plan to, but I solved the issue before someone else answered):

So here is the code that I got to work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        CURL *curl;
        CURLcode res;
        char *feed_addr = "http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KUCP.rss";
        //airport not in the state I live    

        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if(curl) {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, feed_addr);

                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

                //line that solved my issue
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, <string>);
                /**
                 * The line as written will not work.
                 * I'm only using <string> as a stand-in for some personal information
                 * If you're having the same issue as I did, I explain how to solve it under the code
                 */

                // Perform the request, res will get the return code
                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
                // Check for errors
                if(res != CURLE_OK) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",curl_easy_strerror(res));
                }

                // always cleanup
                curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The way I solved this was finding a site that printed out my HTTP request. In this case, it was http://rve.org.uk/dumprequest. I visited the site like normal in one tab, and I used the program to get the source, then launched that in another tab. That was when I saw that several fields were present when I manually opened the page, but absent when I used the code.

So, I looked at curl_easy_setopt to see if there was a way to set those fields. It turns out, curl_easy_setopt has documentation for that and many more at the website https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html. At the suggestion of one of the comments, I looked at CURLOPT_USERAGENT first.

Since that one took a `char *`, I found the line in the HTTP request that started with User-Agent:, copy-and-pasted the rest, and that was `<string>` in the above line.

So if the request included the line:

```
User-Agent: Lord Voldemort (Tom Marvolo Riddle)
```

The line I included would be:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Lord Voldemort (Tom Marvolo Riddle)");
```